# Finding Highest Value in Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there a relatively easy way to find the highest values for each of the keys in my associative arrays?

```
Array(

    0 => Array(
        "avgtime"   => 19.75,
        "bounces"   => 3,
        "pageviews" => 14,
        "visitors"  => 4
    )

    1 => Array(
        "avgtime"   => 1.125,
        "bounces"   => 7,
        "pageviews" => 9,
        "visitors"  => 8
    )

    2 => Array(
        "avgtime"   => 111,
        "bounces"   => 18,
        "pageviews" => 32,
        "visitors"  => 20
    )

    3 => Array(
        "avgtime"   => 6.9375,
        "bounces"   => 14,
        "pageviews" => 18,
        "visitors"  => 10   
    )

    4 => Array(
        "avgtime"   => 191,
        "bounces"   => 11,
        "pageviews" => 57,
        "visitors"  => 24
    )
);
```

I want to create one array that holds the highest value for each key so the end result would be.

```
Array(

    "avgtime"   => 191,
    "bounces"   => 18,
    "pageviews" => 57,
    "visitors"  => 24
);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please. Also, this is basic PHP: use a loop.

Comment: Create a variable with a value of 0 for each array part, loop through your array, update the value if the value is higher than the variable's value.

Comment: You can sort an associative array with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the Array and store the max values for each key

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$key] = max(
                isset($temp[$key]) ? $temp[$key] : $value,
                $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxRecursive(array $arr) {
    $maxArray = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($val, $key) use(&$maxArray){
        if( ( !$maxArray[$key] ) || $maxArray[$key] < $val ){
            $maxArray[$key] = $val;
        }
    });
    return $maxArray;
}
```