# Get highest value from associative array foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, max, associative-array

I'm implementing the first answer shown here: [Finding Highest Value in Associative Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946691/finding-highest-value-in-associative-array)

but what's happening is it assigns the first value it finds as the "max", then when it finds the next highest value, it ALSO assigns "max" to that value.

of course my goal is to only assign "max" to the highest value.

the issue must be the way I present the values.

Here is the array (i'm assigning "max" to the 'sum' index on a PER WEEK basis):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [userid] => 1
            [week] => 1
            [sum] => 28
            [user] => al
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 2
        [sum] => 33
        [user] => al
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 3
        [sum] => 29
        [user] => al
    )
  ...

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 26
        [week] => 1
        [sum] => 14
        [user] => bob
    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 26
        [week] => 2
        [sum] => 23
        [user] => bob
    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 26
        [week] => 3
        [sum] => 35
        [user] => bob
    )
  ...
[34] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 27
        [week] => 1
        [sum] => 36
        [user] => chuck
    )

[35] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 27
        [week] => 2
        [sum] => 23
        [user] => chuck
    )

[36] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 27
        [week] => 3
        [sum] => 29
        [user] => chuck
    )
```

But I'm delivering the data through a couple of foreach loops:

```
<?php
$resultsByUser = array();
$temp = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    $resultsByUser[$result->user][$result->week] = $result->sum;
}
foreach($resultsByUser as $user => $resultsByWeek) {
    print "<tr><td>$user</td>";
    ksort($resultsByWeek);

    foreach($resultsByWeek as $week => $sum) {
        $temp[$week] = max(
                           isset($temp[$week]) ? $temp[$week] : $sum,
                           $sum);                           

        if($week == $week) {    
            if($temp[$week] == $sum) {  ?>                   
                <td><?php echo $sum; ?><span><i class='fa fa-trophy'></i></span></td>
                <?php } else { ?>
            <td><?php echo $sum; ?></td>
            <?php }
        }
    }
} ?>
```

How can I force the $temp[week] aka "max" function to loop through the whole associative array of weekly values before assigning the trophy icon?

EDIT:
After the comments, I've modified the final couple of stanzas to the below, but now I don't get the trophy assigned to any value.  What am I missing?

```
foreach($resultsByWeek as $week => $sum) {
        $temp[$week] = max(
          isset($temp[$week]) ? $temp[$week] : $sum,
                 $sum); ?>                      

        <td><?php echo $sum; }}?>

    <?php if($sum == $temp[$week]) {    ?>  <span><i class='fa fa-trophy'></i></span></td>
                         <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is to have the fa-trophy icon assigned only to the highest value in each week

Comment: Just do the entire loop first and use the value of `max` after the loop is done for your output.

Comment: What's the point of `if($week == $week)`? How can that ever be false?

Comment: You can't know the highest value in each week until you finish the loop. It doesn't make sense to display the trophy icon during the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the answer you received on the other post:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$key] = max(
                isset($temp[$key]) ? $temp[$key] : $value,
                $value);
    }
}
```

You go through all the array of objects, updating the max value as you go through all the data elements.
That means that **you will only have the maximum value (with 100% certainty) when you reach the end of that loop**.

---

If what you want is to print a trophy icon alongside the maximum value, you need to know beforehand what is that element.

You have 2 ways to do that:

**1. Use two loops**

Use a first loop, without writes, just to find the maximum values.
Then use a second loop, with writes, writing the object data. And, if the maximum value gathered in the first loop equals the object data, draw the trophy icon.

Something like:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$key] = max(
                isset($temp[$key]) ? $temp[$key] : $value,
                $value);
    }
}

foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        echo $user_data; 
        if ($user_data_sum == $temp[$key])
            echo "<trophy image>"; 
    }
}
```

**2. Save on the object that it is the maximum value (or the trophy)**

If you can edit the objects, save the maximum value on the object. That will reduce the processing time, since you'll only need a single loop instead of two as above.

Something like:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 1
        [sum] => 28
        [user] => al
        [is_max] => false
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 2
        [sum] => 33
        [user] => al
        [is_max] => true
    )
```

Using on the loop:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        echo $user_data; 
        if ($user_data_is_max)
            echo "<trophy image>"; 
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 1
        [sum] => 28
        [user] => al
        [trophy] => ""
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 1
        [week] => 2
        [sum] => 33
        [user] => al
        [trophy] => "<trophy image>"
    )
```

Using on the loop just prints (without needing the if):

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
        echo $user_data . $user_data_trophy; 
    }
}
```

Comment: great thanks for your thoughtful and detailed answer.  I decided to loop twice (your first suggestion) and found success.  I will explore your 2nd suggestion when time permits.